# Spring security @PreAuthorize SecurityExpressionRoot or PermissionEvaluator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Spring Security `@PreAuthorize` takes in a lot of expressions, but how does it decide the class of the method in the expression, for e.g

`@PreAuthorize("hasRole()")` is from `SecurityExpressionRoot` and `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission()")` is from `PermissionEvaluator` class. How does it decide which class instance to use?

I'm not very familiar Spring AOP so not able to dig in lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hasPermission` expression is also evaluated against `SecurityExpressionRoot`, but the latter delegates to a `PermissionEvaluator`. You can see this easily if you [have a look at the `SecurityExpressionRoot` source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.java#L135).

By default, permission expressions are [automatically denied](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.x/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.java#L27), but setting a different instance controls the way the `hasPermission` expression behaves.